# Iterate over a very large number of files in a folder

Tags: python, windows

What is the fastest way to iterate over all files in a directory using NTFS and Windows 7, when the filecount in the directory is bigger than 2.500.000?
All Files are flat under the top-level directory.

Currently I use

```
for root, subFolders, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        f = os.path.join(root,file)
        with open(f) as cf:
            [...]
```

but it is very very slow. The process has been running for about an hour and still has not processed a single file but still grows with about 2kB of Memory Usage per second.

Comment: Would it be an option to restructure the filesystem so that, instead of one folder with lots of files, you'd have a bunch of folders, each containing some of the files?

Comment: yes, that would be an idea. but it would also take long to iterate here and move files?

Comment: 1000000000 files in a flat directory or in a directory tree? In the later case, how deep is the tree?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux sry that was overedited... actually its 2.5m in a flat directory

Comment: for the memory problem, try swapping 'for file in files' by a generator (for lazy evaluation) : " gen = (filex for filex in files); for file in gen: etc. "

Comment: @georges using a generator is definitly a must here. But I think the major problem is `os.walk` trying to return the _list_ of all files in the directory. I think in that particular case, we have to find an other solution to obtain the files names one by one. `glog.iglob` is a such function since it returns an iterator. I have modified my answer below accordingly. I would be curious to see if it ease things or not...

Comment: Isn't it the 'open' call that is taking lot of time ? Can you just try  listing of the file names commenting out the 'open' statement and see how much time it takes for the file listing.

Comment: @sateesh The OP does state precisely _where_ the program is "stuck". I was thinking of `os.walk` but as you notices, maybe it is after that?

Comment: i found https://github.com/benhoyt/scandir which should work better for this issue

Answer (score 10):

By default [`os.walk`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) walk the directory tree bottom-up. If you have a deep tree with many leafs, I *guess* this could leave to performances penalties -- or at least for an increased "statup" time, since `walk` has to read lots of data before processing the first file.

All of this being speculative, have you tried to force a topdown explorations:

```
for root, subFolders, files in os.walk(rootdir, topdown=True):
    ...
```

---

**EDIT:**

As the files appear to be in a flat directory, maybe [`glob.iglob`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html#glob.iglob) could leave to better performance by returning an iterator (whereas other method like `os.walk`, `os.listdir` or `glob.glob` build first the *list* of all files). Could you try something like that:

```
import glob

# ...
for infile in glob.iglob( os.path.join(rootdir, '*.*') ):
    # ...
```

Comment: I found out that all these functions are that bad, until the Filesystem has build up its index file. after the b-tree for the directory is created by windows (which is done when you first iterrated over the structure) everything starts up in seconds.

Comment: Very interesting. Yet a little bit disappointing concerning the `glob.iglob`-based answer. I'm not very familiar with Windows, so I don't necessary understand well. How did you solve the problem? By _manually_ pointing your "explorer" to the directory? Or the index was rebuilt _automagically_ during the first run of the Python program?

Comment: It seems windows is a little bit weird in that point... when the B-Tree isnt build up, you wont get an iterator or something like that. If there is such a tree, you will receive immediatly the iterator and can proceed. but somehow the tree got deleted after I moved around some files - which is strage because as the docs tell me, it should be rebuilded. maybe it isnt rebuilded if it is too large...

Comment: Hi @SylvainLeroux, can you take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/53719293/7644562   please!

Answer (score 10):

I found that  [`os.scandir`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0471/) (in python standard-library since 3.5) seems to actually do the trick also in windows!  (as noted in the comments it does its job equally well on MacOS)!

consider the following example:
*"retrieve 100 paths from a folder that contains millions of files"*

**`os.scandir` achieves this in a fraction of a second**

```py
import os
from itertools import islice
from pathlib import Path
path = Path("path to a folder with a lot of files")

paths = [i.path for i in islice(os.scandir(path), 100))]
```

---

All the other tested options (`iterdir, glob, iglob`) somehow take a ridiculous amount of time even though they are supposed to return iterators...

```py
paths = list(islice(path.iterdir(), 100))
```

```py
paths = list(islice(path.rglob(""), 100))
```

```py
import glob
paths = list(islice(glob.iglob(str(path / "*.*")), 100))
```

Comment: Works also on Mac. This saved me a lot of time (waiting for the list) and pain :) Number of files 1062996 and growing...

Answer (score 2):

I used something like this:

```py
from os import scandir
from os.path import isfile, join, exists
import os

def get_files(path):
    if exists(path):
        for file in scandir(path):
            full_path = join(path, file.name)
            if isfile(full_path):
                yield full_path
    else:
        print('Path doesn\'t exist')

def get_subdirs(path):
    if exists(path):
        for subdir in scandir(path):
            full_path = join(path, subdir.name)
            if not isfile(full_path):
                yield full_path
    else:
        print('Path doesn\'t exist')

def walk_dir(directory):
    yield from get_files(directory)
    for subdir in get_subdirs(directory):
        yield from walk_dir(subdir)
```

the `walk_dir` method returns a generator object which can be used to traverse the file system. At any step in the recursive procedure, no list of directories is created, so the memory never holds the list of all files in any subdirectory.