# How to read the large number of text files from a Directory using Python

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, pythonpath, text-processing

I'm working on a project using Python(3.6) and Django(2) in which I need to read all the text files from a directory one by one, I have written the code but it is reading only 28 files from a folder which has 30 text files at the moment for testing purpose and return an error.

**From `views.py:`**

```
def get_txt_files(base_dir):
    for entry in os.scandir(base_dir):
        if entry.is_file() and entry.name.endswith(".txt"):
            # print(entry.path)
            yield entry.path, entry.name
        elif entry.is_dir():
            yield from get_txt_files(entry.path)
        else:
            print(f"Neither a file, nor a dir: {entry.path}")

for path, name in get_txt_files(obj.textPath):
    print(path)
    sa_response = nlp_text_manager(path, name)
```

**here's the function to read the files:**

```
def nlp_text_manager(text_path, name):
    text = text_path
    txt = Path(text_path).read_text(encoding='cp1252')
    # then use the files below that.....
```

And it returns this error after reading 28 files:

> **v = self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)**
>
> **socket.timeout: The read operation timed out**
>
> **[11/Dec/2018 07:16:20] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 500 16416**

The number of files in the provided folder can be very large may the folder has the size in GBs, So, what is the efficient pythonic way to read a large number of files from a directory?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Never run long running process on main thread, use something like `celery` or `cron job` for that.

Comment: @vahidabdi, how can we implement?

Comment: You can read about `celery` documentation [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/index.html), if you have specific question please add new question.

Comment: if they don't change very often, you could also do this at service/server startup time…  the idea is to move time consuming code away from HTTP operations

Comment: Hi @SamMason, how can I do that? any resource? please!

Comment: just put the code to do the loading at the "top level", i.e. outside of any definition.  try putting `print` statements in various places to learn how Python/Django loads/evaluates the different parts of your code